# AccessibilityService can't receive onKeyEvent or onGesture

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I'm a Chinese student who is doing some research in Android security.(There may be have some grammar errors in my sentences) I wanna use the accessibility API to capture the user’s behaviors such as clicking the keyboard of IME and selecting certain characters.. But when I tried this API, I could only obtain the text of the current window and the actions that the user performs instead of any events from the keyboard. Maybe I missed something. 
(I can't receive any events from onKeyEvent and onGesture. But I can receive events from onAccessibilityEvent.)

I have created the following basic Accessibility Service.

```
package com.jack.accessibility;

import java.util.List;

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService;
import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfo;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    String eventText = getTypeName(event.getEventType()) + "===="
            + event.getContentDescription();
    Log.e("------------------------", "-------------------------");
    Log.d("PackageName", event.getPackageName().toString());
    Log.d("EventName", eventText);
    traverseNode(getRootInActiveWindow());
    Log.e("------------------------", "-------------------------");
}

@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
    Log.e("---------ServiceConnected--------------",
            "------------ServiceConnected------------");
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    info.packageNames = new String[] { "com.android.mms" };
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPES_ALL_MASK;
    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN;
    info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_FILTER_KEY_EVENTS;
    setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("Key", ".....");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
    Log.v("THEIA", String.format("onGesture: [type] %s", gIdToString(gestureId)));
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    Log.e("---------Interrupt--------------",
            "------------Interrupt------------");
}

private void traverseNode(AccessibilityNodeInfo node) {
    if (null == node)
        return;

    final int count = node.getChildCount();
    if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            AccessibilityNodeInfo childNode = node.getChild(i);
            traverseNode(childNode);
        }
    } else {
        CharSequence text = node.getText();
        Log.d("test", "Node text = " + text);
    }

}
private String getTypeName(int type) {
        switch (type) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_GESTURE_START:
            return "TYPE_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_GESTURE_START";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_GESTURE_END:
            return "TYPE_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_GESTURE_END";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START:
            return "TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_START";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END:
            return "TYPE_TOUCH_INTERACTION_END";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_START:
            return "TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_START";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_END:
            return "TYPE_GESTURE_DETECTION_END";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_EXIT:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_EXIT";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_LONG_CLICKED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_SELECTED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT:
            return "TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_SELECTION_CHANGED";
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_TRAVERSED_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY:
            return "TYPE_VIEW_TEXT_TRAVERSED_AT_MOVEMENT_GRANULARITY";
        }
        return "Unknown";
    }

private String gIdToString(int gID) {
    switch (gID) {
    case 1:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_UP";
    case 2:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN";
    case 3:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT";
    case 4:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT";
    case 5:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT_AND_RIGHT";
    case 6:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT_AND_LEFT";
    case 7:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_UP_AND_DOWN";
    case 8:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN_AND_UP";
    case 9:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT_AND_UP";
    case 10:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_LEFT_AND_DOWN";
    case 11:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT_AND_UP";
    case 12:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_RIGHT_AND_DOWN";
    case 13:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_UP_AND_LEFT";
    case 14:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_UP_AND_RIGHT";
    case 15:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN_AND_LEFT";
    case 16:
        return "GESTURE_SWIPE_DOWN_AND_RIGHT";
    }
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jack.accessibility.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:label="@string/acc_service_name" android:name=".MyAccessibilityService" android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.accessibilityservice" 
            android:resource="@xml/phone_accessibility" />
    </service>

</application>
```

phone_accessibility.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
     android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask" 
     android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask" 
     android:notificationTimeout="100" 
     android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
     android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
     android:canRequestEnhancedWebAccessibility="true"
     android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
     android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this:

```
info.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION_MODE;
```

Answer (score 0):

From `AccessibilityService`, i couldn't get the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` for the `IME` or `Keyboard`.

From what i understood, you are trying to log the keys; but this is not possible. You need to have your own keyboard in order to log the keys pressed on the `Keyboard`.

But from `AccessibilityService`, you can get text content from all `EditText`'s except the Password `EditText`'s (who have `password` as their `inputType`).

Since you have already figured that out, i won't write the code to get text from a node.

If this was possible, would have been a major security issue wouldn't it?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure the Accessibility Service like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeContextClicked|typeViewClicked"
  android:packageNames="com.example.andres.eventcapture"
  android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestFilterKeyEvents"
  android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
  android:notificationTimeout="50"
  android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
  android:settingsActivity=""
  android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
/>
```

It worked good!