# Android - AccessibilityService onGesture method not called

Tags: android, accessibility, gesturedetector

I've implemented a simple AccessibilityService that works fine, meaning -

I receive the AccessibilityEvents through the onAccessibilityEvent() method.

My goal is to get screen swipe events.

The problem is that I can’t get swipe events in the onGesture() method - it just wont get called.

Non of the solutions I found worked out for me - tried -

[similar Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47908864/android-ongesture-method-not-getting-called-in-accessibilityservice/47953826)

[similar Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31312588/accessibilityservice-cant-receive-onkeyevent-or-ongesture)

My service code:

```
public class MyAccessibilityService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyAccessibilityService";

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent accessibilityEvent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAccessibilityEvent");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onGesture(int gestureId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onGesture");
    }
}
```

My service xml metadata:

```
<accessibility-service
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagRequestTouchExplorationMode|flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"
    android:canRequestFilterKeyEvents="true"
    android:packageNames="com.whatsapp"
/>
```

Any idea someone?